# How to apply `where` condition to each record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I want to display the `difference_in_days` for every `HPId`, which is present in a table `AccountClose`.

Here is my code

```
@a = AccountClose.where("AccountCloseId is not null").last.Date.to_date
@before = Date.today 
@difference_in_days = (@before.to_date - @a.to_date).to_i
```

The above query only displays the `difference_in_days` for the last record. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: You are getting difference_in_days only for the last record because you are fetching the last record alone. 

@a = AccountClose.where("AccountCloseId is not null").last.Date.to_date

the last in this statement fetches just the last record.
Hope it clarifies your doubt.

Comment: can you show `AccountClose` schema or table structure?

Comment: AccountClose(AccountCloseId: integer, HPId: integer, UsersId: integer, Date: datetime)

Comment: @TChaitanyaTatavolu You can check the given answer below that's the difference between answer you have marked correct .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **a sidenote ...**
>
> you really should try to follow the rails way. convention over
>   configuration.  that means to take care how to name you database,
>   tables and fields and lots more. it makes life much easier.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails
>   https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails

Answer (score 1):

```
@before = Date.today 
@a = AccountClose.where("AccountCloseId is not null")
@a.each_with_index{|account_close,i|
   @difference_in_days = (@before.to_date - account_close.Date.to_date).to_i 
   puts "Difference in days for account close #{i}: \t #{@difference_in_days}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!But it's showing me the error like 'undefined method to_date'

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `to_date' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000002ddd6760>

Comment: what are the date columns in AccountClose?
a.to_date in this line you need to add a.date_column.to_date

Comment: @TChaitanyaTatavolu How did you accept the answer if its still showing error? lol

Comment: Iam getting error at this line.                                                         @difference_in_days = (@before.to_date - @a.to_date).to_i

Comment: Replace that line with @difference_in_days = (@before.to_date - (@before.to_date - account_close.Date.to_date).to_i .Date.to_date).to_i 

Edited the answer too.
Please do check.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all closed_dates using `pluck` query as array

```
@closed_dates = AccountClose.where("AccountCloseId is not null").pluck('date(Date)')
```

=> [Fri, 20 Jan 2017, Sun, 22 Jan 2017, Sun, 22 Jan 2017, Thu, 02 Feb 2017, Tue, 26 Jun 2018, Wed, 27 Jun 2018, Mon, 02 Jul 2018, Wed, 04 Jul 2018, Wed, 11 Jul 2018, Wed, 11 Jul 2018, Wed, 11 Jul 2018, Thu, 12 Jul 2018, Thu, 12 Jul 2018, Fri, 13 Jul 2018..]

Display difference_in_days for every HPId which is present in AccountClose

```
@closed_dates.each do |colsed_date|
  puts "Difference in days is #{(Date.today - colsed_date).to_i}"
end
```